# How to pause and resume timer and progressbar in android?

Tags: android

I have an activity and have timer with progressbar intially starts and there is a broadcast receiver in that activity which detects network state change if network disabled. I want to stop timer and progressbar, and when Network is enabled again, I want to resume from where timer and progressbar stopped.How could I do that please Tell.

code:-

```
private final BroadcastReceiver m_InternetChecker = new BroadcastReceiver() {/*Receiver to check Network state*/
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        init();

    }
};

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.otp_auto_verified);
    /*Registering Broadcast receiver*/
    IntentFilter m_internetFilter = new IntentFilter();// creating object of Intentfilter class user for defining permission
    m_internetFilter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");// action to check Internet connection
    getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(m_InternetChecker, m_internetFilter);// register receiver....

}
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
private void init() {// initialize view controls
    if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(getApplicationContext())) {
        m_AlertDialog.dismiss();
        //Initialize a new CountDownTimer instance
        long m_MillisInFuture = 30000;// timer value
        long m_CountDownInterval = 1000;// timer break up
        m_oTimer = new CountDownTimer(m_MillisInFuture, m_CountDownInterval) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                millis = millisUntilFinished;
                @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)));
                System.out.println(hms);
                tv.setText(hms);
                //Another one second passed
                //Each second ProgressBar progress counter added one

                m_n_ProgressStatus += 1;
                m_timerProgress.setProgress(m_n_ProgressStatus);
            }

            public void onFinish() {// when timer finished
            /*This is new change ....check if app is in backround or foreground*/
            /*if app is in background*/
                if (NetworkUtil.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
                    System.out.println("In Background");
                    Intent i = new Intent(COtpAutoVerificationScreen.this, COtpManualVerificationScreen.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("In Foreground");
                    CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Otp not found", getApplicationContext());
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Intent i = new Intent(COtpAutoVerificationScreen.this, COtpManualVerificationScreen.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }, 3500);
                }
            }
        }.start();// start timer
        // retreive progress bar count........
        int progressBarMaximumValue = (int) (m_MillisInFuture / m_CountDownInterval);
        //Set ProgressBar maximum value
        //ProgressBar range (0 to maximum value)

        m_timerProgress.setMax(progressBarMaximumValue);

    } else {
        m_oTimer.cancel();
        m_n_ProgressStatus = 0;
        m_AlertDialog.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually updating your progress bar in onTick(long) function. So once the timer is paused the progress bar is also the same. And unfortunately i cant find any method to pause it.

I would add something to the onTick handler to save the progress of the timer in your class variable like number of millisecond sec left.

Then once network is disable you can  call cancel() of the timer and save value of millisecond left and progress bar state(value).

And once network enabled activity create a new timer with the saved number of milliseconds left.